# shell: Validate for multiple alphabets in an if statement

Tags: bash, shell, ksh

I know this was asked multiple times with respect to validating multiple variables. This however is a if condition to validate for single letters(alphabets).

I have a statement that goes like this. The arguments are passed from another script

```
action=$1
name=$2
gname=$3

echo "action is $action name is $name and gname is $gname" # making sure i got the args passed right

#if [ $action != B ] || [ $action != T ] || [ $action != R ] ; // This WORKS!!
if [ $action != [ B | R | T ]; then // Returns an error
echo "NADA"
exit
fi

if [ $name != SNAP1 ] || [ $name != SNAP2 ] || [ $name != SNAP3 ] ; 
echo "NADA"
exit
fi
```

I'd like to know how to compare more than just those 3 letters and 3 variables. What if i want to validate more than say 8 letters, is there a better way to write the if statement, how can i shorten the comparison?

Comment: Are you limited to POSIX sh statements? You could use `case` for pattern comparison. Can you use Bash statement? You could use `[[ ]]` pattern matching.

Comment: In ksh you can use : if [[ $action = !(B|R|T) ]]; then........

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case`:

```
case "$action" in
   [BRT]) ;;
    *) echo "NADA" ;;
esac
```